# $f(f(n))+f(n+1)=n+2$, where $n \in \mathbb N^*_+$

Tags: functional-equations

Does there exist a function $ f:\mathbb{N}_+^* \to \mathbb{N}_+^*$ such that$ f(f(n))+f(n+1)=n+2$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_+^*$ ?

What I found is that $f(1)=1$ because
We have $f(n)\leq n$
Suppose $f(1)=a>1$
For $n=1 f(a)+f(2)=3$
So

1. $f(a)=1 $
   For $n=a-1$
   We have $f(f(a-1))=a+1$ which is a contradiction
   Or
2. $f(a)=2$. For $n=a-1$. We have
   $$f(f(a-1))=a$$
   which is a contradiction

Comment: What is $N^*_+$ ?

Comment: (N) : integers, (+) : Positive  (*) : different from 0

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
As you say, $f(1)=1$ and $f(n)\leqslant n$.
Write the functional equation as:
$$f(f(n-1))+ f(n)= n+1$$
and rearrange:
$$f(n) = n+1-f(f(n-1))$$
This gives us a way to iterate through $f(n)$ based on previous values. Note that $f(n-1) \leqslant n-1$ and so is known and so $f(f(n-1)) \leqslant n-1$ and so $f(n)$ will always be $>0$.
The pattern seems slightly chaotic:

[image]

Comment: Ah, it's related to the Beatty sequence.